# How to test debounceTime in angular 4 form

Tags: angular

I have a field on a form which is a search filter. When user enters a value in that search field, new results are fetched and view is filter. Below is the form

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
<span>Enter State:</span><input id="txtState" formControlName="stateControl"  type="text" />
<div>// data<div>
</form>
```

component code

```
 const stateCtrl=this.form.get("stateControl");
stateCtrl.valueChanges.debounceTime(2000).subscribe((data)=>//serviceCall)
```

test.ts

```
 let state=component.form.controls["stateControl"];
      state.setValue("Texas");

      fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable()
            .then(()=>
            {
              fixture.detectChanges();
              expect(component.customers.length).toBe(5)
            })
```

The issue is, this test is always successful. No matter what is the value in .toBe(). the code is not waiting for debounce. How to write a test for debounce in angular 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `tick` function to simulate the passage of time.

[Tick function Angular.io docs](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick)

Place it before your assertion and make the time equal to your debounce timer.